# Java: try/catch with InputMismatchException creates infinite loop while reading of a file

Tags: java, file, loops, try-catch, java.util.scanner

I have a task to make a program that will add up all the valid integers in a file and to ignore anything that isn’t a valid int. I have to use Try and Catch.

```
File Numbers = new File("Numbers.txt");
    Scanner readFile = null;
    int i = 0;
    int total= 0;

    boolean success = false;

    while(!success){    
        try {
        readFile = new Scanner(Numbers);
        while(readFile.hasNext()){  
            i = readFile.nextInt();
            System.out.println(i);
            total = i + total;
            };
        success = true;// Ends The loop

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
            System.err.println(Numbers.getName()+" does not exist");
        }
        catch(InputMismatchException e2){
            System.err.println("Data incorrect type expecting an int found:  " + readFile.nextLine());

            readFile.next();
        }

    System.out.println("total is: " + total);
    };
```

The problem is that the program gets caught in an infinite loop, where instead of going past the exception it just starts again.The task seems pretty straight forward, yet i don't know why it wont work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You fall into infinite loop because when exception happens, the `success` variable didn't change its value to `true`. In order to do some action *even when exception happens* you should add the `finnaly` block. It could look like this:

```
try {
    // do some stuff
} catch (Exception e) {
    // catch the exception
} finally {
    if (!readFile.hasNext()) success = true;
}
```

And by the way, **never do this: `catch (Exception e)`**, I did it just for example sake. Instead always catch the specific exception. Because `Exception` is the most basic class in the exception hierarchy, so it will catch up **all** the exceptions, and unless you re-throw it you could have false feeling of "safiness". When you want to catch all the exceptions, you should do this:

```
try {
    // do stuff
} catch (RuntimeException e) {
    throw e;
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace(); // or other approptiate action, i.e. log it.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the finally stops the endless loop but, the program cant get passed the Input mismatch on the file

Comment: My bad, I made a mistake in the answer. It should be `success = true;`, of course. I edited the question.

Comment: @Sparky in the `finally` block, try to insert the condition: `if (!readFile.hasNext()) success = true;`

Comment: Thank  you for help much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Assume any of the following FileNotFound or InputMismatchException exceptions will raise, then your program wont change success to true. Thus it returns to the outer while loop and read the same file. Because nothing has changed the same Exception will be thrown again.

==> Endless loop.

To fix that I suggest to move the try/catch block to the inner while.